# how to set success message for successful mysql update and for error

Tags: php, mysqli

Consider the following mysql table:

table: information

```
id | name | address | mobile
----------------------------
 1 | Mr.X | Japan | 95321663
 2 | Mr.Y | USA | 1458963201
```

Here, id is PRIMARY key and name and address is UNIQUE columns.
Now while I update the table by the following query:

```
UPDATE information SET name='Mr.Z', address='Japan', mobile=95321663 WHERE id=1;
```

it successfully updates the table, but if I try by:

```
UPDATE information SET name='Mr.X', address='Japan', mobile=95321663 WHERE id=1;
```

It is not updating the database. I catch the update success by following php code:

```
if($this->conn->affected_rows>=1{
   echo 'Data updated successfully!';
}else{
   echo 'Data could not be updated due to: '.$this->conn->err;
}
```

Note that, in 2nd query, all field value of mysql table is same (for id=1).

I want to set an error message if there is any error in sql syntax or other type error.

How to achieve this?

Comment: This is by design. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-affected-rows.html

Comment: Then how can I set a message for successful update and for any error?

Comment: I have changed the question.

Comment: Simply check the return value from [`execute()`](http://php.net/manual/mysqli-stmt.execute.php)